# Accessing a range of elements from any point in an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, xml, ienumerable

I have this method:

```
private IEnumerable<XElement> ReadTransactions(string file_name)
    {
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(file_name + ".xml"))
        {
            while (reader.ReadToFollowing("transaction", "urn:namepsaceUri"))
            {
                using (var subtree = reader.ReadSubtree())
                {
                    yield return XElement.Load(subtree);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This method reads from an XML file. However, I don't need all of the nodes in the XML file at same time.

I want to get them ten at a time.

I tried working with XPathSelectElements, but that gets all the nodes, and then I need to iterate through them.

So, is there a way to get the nodes from the XML file which are 40-50? I want to modify `ReadTransactions` - to have another input parameter (40 in this case), and instead of all the elements, it will return just 10?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about [Skip()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb358985.aspx) and [Take()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062.aspx) extensions methods?

```
var items = ReadTransactions(file_name).Skip(40).Take(10);
```

Answer (score 24):

what about **ElementAt**

seems to me this is what you are looking for

Comment: This answer the question in the title, which was what I was looking for, so thank you.

Comment: Fwiw, original title was, "_Accessing nth element of IEnumerable_", so @HenriqueMiranda and the answer is on the [original title] money here.

Comment: Funny thing that I googled for the nth element of IEnumerable and got linked to here. Guess google indexed this for that question. Thanks for this answer :)