# Finding a value of a dictionary using an index in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

simple question here for C# unity.

Is there an easy, or any way at all to find the key pair associated with an index like you can in an array?

Like this:

`myDictionary[0]`

Should return a key-value pair which I can use.

Pretty simple, that's it.

Comment: Since dictionaries don't have concept of "index" it is somewhat hard to know what you expect to happen, but fortunately we have duplicate that covers all sorts of "first" cases for Dictionary.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was asking for an index not just the first one. Like Dictionary[2] should work too

Comment: You *really* should not be doing it... But look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295086/accessing-a-range-of-elements-from-any-point-in-an-ienumerable if you really need to access semi-random element at given index. Using data structure that supports indexing (like list or array) would likely make more sense... you can even convert dictionary to one - with `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`.